# Как сделать отображение текста в зависимости от того на какой заголовок нажали?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Мне нужно сделать как то так чтобы когда нажимается на заголовок слева справа отображался текст который к нему относится. Делаю это на React. Компонент получает вот такие props :

```
helpTabData : {
 [
            {
                articleName : 'Article 1',
                text : '1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'
            },
            {
                articleName : 'Article 2',
                text : '22222222222222222222222222222222222222222'
            },
            {
                articleName : 'Article 3',
                text : '3333333333333333333333333333333333'
            }
]
```

Как видно если нажимаем на Article 3 то отображается относящийся к нему text (в моем случае '3333333333333333333333333333333333')

Может можно как то использовать что-то в виде key атрибута? Но как то не получается понять как это сделать лучше и правильней)

Вот так сейчас выглядит :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код компонента :

```
import React from 'react';

import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
});

function HelpTab(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>


          <Grid container spacing= {24}>
                        <Grid sm = {3}>
                        <List component="nav">
                        {props.helpTabData.map(article =>
                            <ListItem button>
                                <ListItemText primary= {article.articleName} />
                            </ListItem>
                            )}
                        </List>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid sm = {9}>
                            <Typography>
                            Nunc. Montes parturient dapibus vehicula. Erat eros in taciti dictumst a felis auctor sit imperdiet congue. Sodales dis. Netus pharetra mollis orci, quisque non suscipit primis Litora. Lectus. Eu hendrerit rhoncus pellentesque dolor lacinia scelerisque penatibus viverra gravida magna nec, eleifend proin risus nunc netus posuere. Eleifend pede class blandit convallis.

                            Nec suspendisse nullam vitae. A. Placerat quisque Vel vulputate nunc. Non. Scelerisque accumsan vulputate dolor mauris ante lobortis condimentum quis felis platea ridiculus. Quis odio diam amet vel at primis. Mauris. Sit torquent adipiscing, ad velit. Mattis lobortis hendrerit morbi. Diam duis, eleifend cum pulvinar diam.

                            Mi dis. Scelerisque. Pellentesque egestas cum lectus ligula ut. Pretium sit dictumst integer porta imperdiet. Fames. Sociis taciti lacus ultrices, molestie pellentesque ullamcorper pellentesque pharetra phasellus quam imperdiet lectus vehicula cursus orci. Mus venenatis aptent leo habitant bibendum tempor. Enim a sollicitudin luctus dapibus erat. Lobortis faucibus interdum aliquam tempus fames vel eleifend non mollis ipsum facilisi facilisis. Fermentum suscipit fermentum nam tellus eleifend malesuada lacinia a blandit natoque parturient faucibus lacus mi Dis nisi fermentum, etiam penatibus dui platea torquent tellus.

                            Ultrices sed platea hac lorem vehicula. Dignissim ipsum. Ligula eget. Primis tellus dignissim leo conubia condimentum. Nulla duis turpis taciti. Placerat dis nam. Laoreet id, lectus ante inceptos sem nulla Dui ad fermentum sociis hymenaeos convallis quam egestas ultricies, tortor sodales class dignissim senectus pede vitae est potenti hac parturient porttitor. Ac consectetuer vehicula imperdiet.

                            Ridiculus etiam inceptos etiam non mus rhoncus tincidunt velit torquent nulla in arcu enim. Class vitae luctus auctor Cubilia tristique dui etiam molestie montes maecenas sollicitudin pede malesuada ut enim. Felis porta ullamcorper cursus et tortor fringilla. Nam consequat viverra Penatibus Ullamcorper purus duis potenti dui inceptos, lorem justo dictumst tristique magnis. Parturient. Dolor faucibus rutrum inceptos a tortor facilisi parturient porttitor sem non luctus nunc.
                            </Typography>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>

    </div>
  );
}

HelpTab.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(HelpTab);
```

Comment: а где тут обработка клика?

Comment: тебе нужно переделать компонент в контейнер  и менять state  если произошел клик.  таким образом ты сможешь отображать необходимый тебе текс по событию

Comment: обработки клика нету потому что не знаю что в нем писать

Comment: Получается заголовки в компонент отдельный вынести, и текст в отдельный компонент выносить? А как мне сообщить чтобы именно нужный мне текст отображал?

Comment: пока времени нет. гляну позже.

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так сделать

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

class App extends Component {
  state={
  helpTabData: [
      {
        articleName: 'Article 1',
        text: '1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'
      },
      {
        articleName: 'Article 2',
        text: '22222222222222222222222222222222222222222'
      },
      {
        articleName: 'Article 3',
        text: '3333333333333333333333333333333333'
      }
    ]

}
render() {
  return (<HelpTab helpTabData={this.state.helpTabData}/>);
}
}

class HelpTab extends Component {
  state={
    activeTab:1,
  }
  render() {
    const data=this.props.helpTabData;
    return (
      <div >
        <Grid container spacing={24}>
          <Grid sm={3}>
            <List component="nav">
              {data.map((article,key) =>
                <ListItem button key={key} onClick={()=>{ this.setState({activeTab:key})}}>
                  <ListItemText primary={article.articleName} />
                </ListItem>
              )}
            </List>
          </Grid>
          <Grid sm={9}>
            <Typography>
              {data[this.state.activeTab].text}
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```